# PHP Update Query While Loop

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

So I have 2 tables named `accounts` and `tblDataNumbers`. The `accounts` table has a `sponsorID` field while the `tblDataNumbers` table has `xsponsorID` field. So first, this is the code:

```
for ($x = 501; $x <= 1061; $x++) {

    $data = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tblDataNumbers WHERE tableID = $x");

    foreach ($data as $d) {
        $xsponsorID = $d['xsponsorID'];
    }

    $checkSponsor = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE sponsorID = '".$xsponsorID."' ");

    if(count($checkSponsor) > 0) {
        $xsid = $xsponsorID;
    } else {
        $xsid = "";
    }

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE tblDataNumbers SET xsponsorID=:xsponsorID WHERE tableID=:x');
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':xsponsorID'   => $xsid,
        ':x'      => $x
    ));  
}
```

The code above will check if the `$xsponsorID` is existing on the `sponsorID` field of the accounts table. If yes, it will set $xsid to the same value which is `$xsponsorID` and if not, it will be set to blank or `""`. When I run the code, nothing happens. There are lots of numbers in the `xsponsorID` field of the `tblDataNumbersthat` table that is not present in the `sponsorID` field of the `accounts` table so basically something should be set to blank but not even one.

What I wanted to happen with this is to repeat the code inside from row `501` to `1061` of table `tblDataNumbers` but nothing happens. Is there something wrong with my code? Thank you.

Comment: i assume you are getting an error?

Comment: @FewFlyBy Are you missing a comma after this line ':xsponsorID'   => $xsid

Comment: @ReaganGallant Hi I edited, it has a comma

Comment: @Burki just blank. Not even 1 error

Comment: Is `tables` a real name of updated table?

Comment: @Jan.J Hi, thanks. Updated it.

Comment: @ReaganGallant, what do you mean?

Comment: You only have one variable `$xsponsorID` , which is overwritten a lot within your `foreach` loop

Comment: Oh... i just notice: you are never executing your select queries.

Comment: so... : Some basic debugging techniques: have your script generate some output to test your individual steps.

Comment: @Burki : the SELECTs are "executed", without prepared statements. Bit confusing, isn't it? THe whole code - no offense - looks like it has been copy&pasted bit by bit.

Comment: I think you guys have said it all. A lot of missing code.

Comment: @VolkerK, yes without prepared statements because I made it locally only for some updates to my table but will not use this on production.

Comment: echo your queries. do some debugging

Comment: If anybody can help me, please. It will be very much appreciated. I've been working on this for 4 hours already :(

Comment: @ReaganGallant, will do that thanks

Comment: We are already helping. First, generate some debug messages. Preferrably after each action, since you seem to be at the beginning of your learning curve (which is perfectly fine!). Then, try to understand what happens. After that: provide us with more information.

Comment: or open a file in append mode. log to it. anything

Comment: When I try to echo out the values, everything showed. The problem is the update query I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you are attempting but that could potentially kill the server for a while as there will be 560 x records (from 1st query ) = lots!

I think there must be a neater solution that does the work in one query - I shall look at the queries in detail to see if there is a solution.

```
for( $x = 501; $x <= 1061; $x++ ) {

    $data = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tblDataNumbers WHERE tableID = $x");


    /* This loop will only ever get one result..
    foreach( $data as $d ){ 
        $xsponsorID = $d['xsponsorID'];
    }
    */

    foreach( $data as $d ){ 

        $xsponsorID = $d['xsponsorID'];

        $checkSponsor = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE sponsorID = '".$xsponsorID."' ");
        $xsid=( count( $checkSponsor ) > 0 ) ? $xsponsorID : '';

        $stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE `tblDataNumbers` SET `xsponsorID`=:xsponsorID WHERE `tableID`=:x;');
        $stmt->execute(array(
            ':xsponsorID'   => $xsid,
            ':x'            => $x
        ));
    }

}
```

After looking at this again and reading your comments I wondered if something along the lines of the following might do the trick. I created a new database with the same two named tables and populated some test data ( though I do not know if it resembles your own data ) and used the following as a test within [`heidi`](http://www.heidisql.com/download.php) ( mysql gui app )

```
set @tblid=1;
update `tblDataNumbers` t set t.`xsponsorID`=(
    case
        when ( t.`xsponsorID` not in ( select `sponsorID` from `accounts` ) ) then
            null
        else
            t.`xsponsorID`
    end
)
where t.`tableID`=@tblid;
```

Clearly this updates a record where the tableID is equal to the @tblid var only. However, to update all the records that match the criteria, remove the where clause and it will apply the `NULL` value to any record in the `tblDataNumbers` table that does not have a corresponding `sponsorID` in the accounts table. Before running this I would strongly advise making a backup of your data though!!!!

Without the mysql variable the query becomes the following and means you would not need the loops.

```
update `tblDataNumbers` t set t.`xsponsorID`=(
    case
        when ( t.`xsponsorID` not in ( select `sponsorID` from `accounts` ) ) then
            null
        else
            t.`xsponsorID`
    end
)
```

If it is important to update the records only between 501 and 1061 then you could add a where clause such as:-

```
where t.`tableID` between 501 and 1061
```

Comment: Thank you. Will try this and update you if this is what am I rooting for.

Comment: When I try to echo out the values, everything showed. The problem is the update query I think. But when I tried to echo out the values, everything showed. The problem is the update query I think.

Comment: I have been looking at this - what is it that you are attempting to do with these queries? You select a field called `xsponsorID` in the outer loop repeatedly, check that it exists in the `accounts` table and, regardless of it it does or does not, then update the `tblDataNumbers` with exactly the same value... Although if it does not exist in the `accounts` table you update a record with an empty tableID? Is it supposed to update with a new value from somewhere?

Comment: If the `xsponsorID` value exists on the `sponsorID` values then the value should stay the same, else it would be set to blank.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @RamRaider, managed to fix it by adding a single line and removing the count() function.

```
for( $x = 501; $x <= 1061; $x++ ) {

    $data = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tblDataNumbers WHERE tableID = $x");


    foreach( $data as $d ){ 

        $xsponsorID = $d['xsponsorID'];

        $checkSponsor = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE sponsorID = '".$xsponsorID."' ");
        $row = $checkSponsor->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //I forgot this line
        $xsid=( $row > 0 ) ? $xsponsorID : '';

        $stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE `tblDataNumbers` SET `xsponsorID`=:xsponsorID WHERE `tableID`=:x;');
        $stmt->execute(array(
            ':xsponsorID'   => $xsid,
            ':x'            => $x
        ));
    }

}
```